# How to exactly filter some delay date if it appears in my df or find the next ahead

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, dynamic

I need to filter exact dates ranges delay in my df, but I don´t know how to solve this in R.

If the filter didn´t find some date (row) in my df then go to the next date delay.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- 
  data.frame(
    fcst.dates = c(
      "2022-01-01",
      "2022-01-02",
      "2022-01-03",
      "2022-01-05",
      "2022-01-06",
      "2022-01-08",
      "2022-01-09",
      "2022-01-11",
      "2022-01-12",
      "2022-01-13",
      "2022-01-14",
      "2022-01-17"
    ),
    y = rnorm(12, 0, 1),
    yhat = rnorm(12, 0, 1)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    fcst.dates = as.Date(fcst.dates),
    Obs = max(fcst.dates) - fcst.dates,
    delay = as.numeric(Obs)
  )
```

But imagine that I need to filter 13 days delayed in the past...

```
filter0 <- df %>%
  filter(
    delay == 13
  )
```

It obviously retunrs 0 in this filter. But how can I change it to dynamically change if the filter didn´t find 13 for the next value (for ex. 14 or 15) ?

Comment: What about? `df %>%  filter(delay >= 13) %>% head(1)`

Comment: [Side note, if your example relies on random numbers and it would help for everyone to work with the same data, add `set.seed(0)` (or a number of your choosing) at the start of the code, so we work with the same pseudo random numbers.]

Comment: @harre thanks, but it doesn´t solve my issue...I need to make filter use automatically 14 or 15...

Comment: @Rodrigo: Then use `tail` instead of `head`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this might do the trick:

```
df %>%
  filter(delay >= 13) %>% 
  tail(1)
```